Algebraic simplification of a high-order gaussian equation results in imaginary values
I have a modified high-order gaussian curve that I want to simplify algebraically. So far, I've been able to distill it down to this point:
$$f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\left(2 + \frac{2}{n}\right)^2}{b^2}(x-x_0)^2\right)^n}$$
In this equation, $x_0$ is the center point of the gaussian, $n$ is the "high-order" power that's shaping the curve, and $b$ is effectively the "width of the base"(for a normal gaussian curve when $n=1$, the width $b=4\sigma$).
After getting here, I just assumed that I could pull squared term outside of the parentheses - lets call this simplified equation $g$ and define it as follows:
$$f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\left(2 + \frac{2}{n}\right)}{b}(x-x_0)\right)^{2n}}$$
The issue I'm having is that doing this --almost-- works. When I plot the two functions together in matlab, $f(x) = g(x)$ only when $n=1$ or $n\ge2$   (I'm only looking at positive $n$ values).
The functions are not equivalent when $n$ is in the range $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ because $g(x)$ apparently starts generating complex numbers on the left side of the function, but the right side is still identical to $f(x)$
f(x) and g(x) co-plotted with different n values
Does anybody know why this happens? I've double checked the code/math a bunch of times so I feel like I'm missing something super obvious here
for reference, here is the matlab code used to generate the comparison plot $(x_0 = 0, b = 2, n = [1, 1.2, 1.8, 2])$
f = @(x,x0,b,n) exp(-0.5 .* ( (x-x0).^2 ./ b.^2  .* (2 + 2./n).^2) .^ n );
g = @(x,x0,b,n) exp(-0.5 .* ( (x-x0)./b.*(2 + 2./n) ) .^ (2.*n) );

x = -2:0.01:2;
x0 = 0;
b = 2;

figure('position',[50 50 800 800])

subplot(4,1,1); hold on; grid on; xlim([min(x) max(x)]); ylim([-0.4 1.2])
n = 1;
plot(x,f(x,x0,b,n),'b-','linewidth',2)
plot(x,g(x,x0,b,n),'r-.','linewidth',1.3)
legend(sprintf('f(x): n = %.1f',n) ,sprintf('g(x): n = %.1f',n),'location','ne')

subplot(4,1,2); hold on; grid on; xlim([min(x) max(x)]); ylim([-0.4 1.2])
n = 1.2;
plot(x,f(x,x0,b,n),'b-','linewidth',2)
plot(x,g(x,x0,b,n),'r-.','linewidth',1.3)
legend(sprintf('f(x): n = %.1f',n) ,sprintf('g(x): n = %.1f',n),'location','ne')

subplot(4,1,3); hold on; grid on; xlim([min(x) max(x)]); ylim([-0.4 1.2])
n = 1.8;
plot(x,f(x,x0,b,n),'b-','linewidth',2)
plot(x,g(x,x0,b,n),'r-.','linewidth',1.3)
legend(sprintf('f(x): n = %.1f',n) ,sprintf('g(x): n = %.1f',n),'location','ne')

subplot(4,1,4); hold on; grid on; xlim([min(x) max(x)]); ylim([-0.4 1.2])
n = 2;
plot(x,f(x,x0,b,n),'b-','linewidth',2)
plot(x,g(x,x0,b,n),'r-.','linewidth',1.3)
legend(sprintf('f(x): n = %.1f',n) ,sprintf('g(x): n = %.1f',n),'location','ne')


what happenes with the log of the expression?
